# flutter The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
String newValue.
hi, i have the above error when trying to implement a dropdown list menu in flutter

bellow is my code. please i am new to flutter

```
class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {

  String dropdownvalue = 'Apple';
  var items =  ['Apple','Banana','Grapes','Orange','watermelon','Pineapple'];

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold( ....


 child: DropdownButton(
                value: dropdownvalue,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  items:items.map((String items) {
                       return DropdownMenuItem(
                           value: items,
                           child: Text(items)
                       );
                          }
                          ).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String newValue){
                          setState(() {
                            dropdownvalue = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errors like this are null-safety related, you can learn more about null-safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

If you check out the [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) Class in the official docs you can see an example in which the [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/onChanged.html) property is used:

```
 onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
```

If you checkout the [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/onChanged.html) property implementation:

```
final ValueChanged<T?>? onChanged;
```

The `T?` means it requires a **nullable type**, like `String?` instead of a *non-nullable type*, like `String`.

Comment: For problems like this it really helps to check out the flutter api, by just googling for the widget - most of the time their examples aready help you out. And I would strongly recommend reading the first link (article about null-safety), as it is a fundamental change to the underlying dart language :)

Answer (score 1):

The argument type of **onChanged** is `void Function(String?)`. So you can't assign a function of argument type `void Function(String)`

So please change the code as following:

(change the `String` type to `String?` in "**onChanged**" argument

```
class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {

 String dropdownvalue = 'Apple';
 var items =  ['Apple','Banana','Grapes','Orange','watermelon','Pineapple'];

   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
   double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
   return Scaffold( ....


child: DropdownButton(
               value: dropdownvalue,
                 icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                 items:items.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: items,
                          child: Text(items)
                      );
                         }
                         ).toList(),
                       onChanged: (String? newValue){
                         setState(() {
                           dropdownvalue = newValue;
                         });
                       },
                     ),
```

Comment: thanks alot man. it worked for me. you really saved me!